# How can I detect that Unity used error default shader through code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

Is there any way in Unity to know, that there is magenta error shader present in the scene via script? Like, can we really know through code, that material, rendered in scene is actually magenta pink and not one we wanted?

```
void Start() 
{ 
    Renderer[] renderers = FindObjectsOfType<Renderer>(); 
    foreach (var renderer in renderers) 
    { 
        foreach (var mat in renderer.materials) 
        { 
            if (mat.shader.name == "Hidden/InternalErrorShader") 
            { 
                //message 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

This code always returns shader, assigned to an object in editor, not the default magenta error shader unity actually renders.

I expect a way to determine the magenta error shader is rendered not just by eyes, but with code